# Position 3 divs horizontally inside footer

Tags: html, css

I having problems positioning the divs horizontally inside my footer. I need the divs inside the footer to have the equal amount of space between them.

Here's what i've done so far

```
           #submitemail
         {

         float:right;
         margin-right: 280px;
       }
      .footerinfo3
      {

          float: left;
       margin-right: 280px;
      }
      .footerinfo1
      {


       float: left;
       margin-right: 280px;
      }
```

Here's rest of the code
http://jsfiddle.net/U3RXD/

Comment: You should check out http://csswizardry.com/csswizardry-grids/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all the float has to be left float:left; [read this](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a example using `display:inline-block;`

## [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SuLKA/1/)

```
footer{
    width:100%;
    background:#EEEEEE;
    height:400px;
    text-align:center;
}

footer div{
    width:30%;
    height:90%;
    margin:2.5% 0 2.5%  0;
    background:white;
    display:inline-block;
}  

<footer>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</footer>
```

Just a quick note, if you decide to use the `float:left;` in all of the other answers you may need to add a clearfix to your parent container so that it still takes care of the children,

## Clearfix

IE8+

```
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

## Cross Browser Clearfix

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 1):

```
#footer div{
    width: 32%; 
    margin-left: 1%;
    float: left;
}
```

## [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mjLV/2/)

Comment: when you resize browser, they overlaps

Answer (score 0):

Put your html into the ul,li order list as #one,#two,#three (I updated your html,css codes)

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
        <div class="divwrapper">
            <ul>
                <li id="one">
                    <div class="footerinfo1">
                         <h1>Contact</h1>

                        <p>Company Name
                            <br>720 Fifth Avenue
                            <br>New York NY,10019
                            <br>USA</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="two">
                    <div class="footerinfo3">
                         <h1>Contact</h1>

                        <p>Company Name
                            <br>720 Fifth Avenue
                            <br>New York NY,10019
                            <br>USA</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="three">
                    <div class="dark">
                        <form id="submitemail">
                             <h1>Subscribe</h1>

                            <div class="dark"> <span><input type="text" class="check" placeholder="Please enter your email....">  
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></span>

                            </div </form>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#one, #two, #three {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:33%;
}
```

**JS demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/U3RXD/3/

Comment: when you resize browser, they overlaps .

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need :)

```
.divwrapper {
margin:auto 0;
margin-bottom: 400px;
width: 100%;
}

 #footer {
padding-left: 10px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image:url("../images/footer.png") ; 
    position: relative;
margin-top: -214px; /* negative value of footer height */
height: 214px;
clear:both;
    width: 100%;

 }

 .textcontent
{
padding-top: 20px;
float:left;
text-align: justify;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
 #submitemail
{

float:right;
margin-right: 280px;
}
.footerinfo1,
.footerinfo3,
.dark {
 float: left;
 }
.footerinfo1,
.footerinfo3 {
margin-right: 50px;
}
```